# Kotlin Ternary Conditional Operator

Tags: kotlin, conditional-operator

What is the equivalent of this expression in Kotlin?

```
a ? b : c
```

This is not valid code in Kotlin.

Comment: Official discussion: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/ternary-operator/2116

Comment: Maybe the showing the assignment would make this more clear.  "d = (a) ? b : c" is now "d = if (a) b else c.  Same works for when: "d = when { a -> b; c -> x; else ->d }".  Personally I prefer the java/c/PERL syntax.

Comment: Yep, the good designers of kotlin threw away the most elegant construct in java, replacing it with something that's 1) less readable, 2) harder to type (ie more "boilerplate code"), and 3) harder to understand for beginners (conflating expressions with statements).  I think they changed the ternary because...it was java, which by their definition *has* to be bad.

Comment: Using if-else expression in one single line statement is like ternary operator in Java. Kotlin does not support any ternary operator.

Comment: I am working with both C# and Kotlin already for years and I am still missing the `? :` operator in Kotlin. It's just more elegant, shorter and better to read than `if () else` construct. That's why this question has so high rating.

Comment: perl's implementation of the ternary operator allowed code to be included. For example: x = (some condition) ? doThis(): doThat();  Kotlin's Elvis Operator is a null check, only.

Answer (score 1121, accepted):

In Kotlin, `if` statements are expressions. So the following code is equivalent:

```
if (a) b else c
```

The distinction between expression and statement is important here. In Java/C#/JavaScript, `if` forms a statement, meaning that it does not resolve to a value. More concretely, you can't assign it to a variable.

```
// Valid Kotlin, but invalid Java/C#/JavaScript
var v = if (a) b else c
```

If you're coming from a language where `if` is a statement, this might seem unnatural but that feeling should soon subside.

Comment: Additionally you can use `when`.

Comment: just to add, if it's a boolean expression, you can even go with `x = a==b`

Comment: Special mention for `var v = a ?: b`. This is same as `var v = if(a != null) a else b`

Comment: Having Elvis operator, but not Ternary, is a sheer stupidity. However, this could have been rectified a little by adapting pythonic way of doing ternary, `b if (a) else c`, instead of, `if (a) b else c`. Btw, I'm not a fan of that either.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari No, it is not rectifying. It is worse. Compare this. `b + if (a) c else d` vs. `b + (c if (a) else d)` The latter one requires additional parentheses. because `c` is not enclosed by the condition and `else`.

Comment: The Pythonic way is more English-ish, but far less mathematical. It requires additional syntax structure. Currently, every `if` statement or `when` statement is actually an *expression*, so *it just works* as the ternary operator. However, `b if (a) else c` does not just work as it is. It conflicts the fact that a `if` statement is actually an expression if we remove `if (a) b else c` and add `b if (a) else c`. It also breaks the consistency with `when`.

Comment: Here is a little discussion about this topic. https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/ternary-operator/2116/141

Comment: Kotlin coding guidelines prefers using `if` versus `when` on certain conditions as described here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#if-versus-when

Comment: Reminds me of Ada's 'if-expression'
https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/imperative_language.html#if-expressions

Comment: poor design choice.. but of the whole language this is the only other poor design choice I can think of other than the whopper of making default access public wtf

Answer (score 172):

#### TL;DR

```
if (a) b else c
```

^ is what you can use instead of the ternary operator expression `a ? b : c` which Kotlin syntax does not allow.

---

In Kotlin, many control statements, such as `if`, `when`, and even `try`, can be used as **expressions**. As a result, these statements can have a result which may be assigned to a variable, be returned from a function, etc.

#### Syntactically, there's no need for ternary operator

As a result of Kotlin's expressions, the language **does not really need the ternary operator**.

```
if (a) b else c
```

is what you can use instead of the ternary operator expression `a ? b : c`.

I think the idea is that the former expression is more readable since everybody knows what `ifelse` does, whereas `? :` is rather unclear if you're not familiar with the syntax already.

*Nevertheless, I have to admit that I often **miss** the more convenient ternary operator.*

---

**Other Alternatives**

**when**

You might also see `when` constructs used in Kotlin when conditions are checked. It's also a way to express if-else cascades in an alternative way. The following corresponds to the OTs example.

```
when(a) {
    true -> b
    false -> c
}
```

**Extensions**

As many good examples ([Kotlin Ternary Conditional Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500/kotlin-ternary-conditional-operator/39687177#39687177)) in the other answers show, extensions can also help with solving your use case.

Answer (score 105):

You could define your own `Boolean` extension function that returns `null` when the `Boolean` is `false` to provide a structure similar to the ternary operator:

```
infix fun <T> Boolean.then(param: T): T? = if (this) param else null
```

This would make an `a ? b : c` expression translate to `a then b ?: c`, like so:

```
println(condition then "yes" ?: "no")
```

**Update:**
But to do some more Java-like conditional switch you will need something like that

`infix fun <T> Boolean.then(param: () -> T): T? = if (this) param() else null`

`println(condition then { "yes" } ?: "no")`
pay attention on the lambda. its content calculation should be postponed until we make sure `condition` is `true`

This one looks clumsy, [that is why there is high demanded request exist to port Java ternary operator into Kotlin](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5823)

Comment: `infix inline fun<T> Boolean.then(param: ()->T):T? = if(this) param() else null`

Comment: Use <T:Any>, otherwise that will work incorrectly: `true then { null } ?: "not-null"`

Comment: BTW, the `?:` operator here is `elvis-operator`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator

Answer (score 59):

Java's equivalent of ternary operator

```
a ? b : c
```

is a simple IF in Kotlin in one line

```
if(a) b else c
```

> there is no ternary operator (condition ? then : else), because
>   ordinary if works fine in this role.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression

---

**Special case for Null comparison**

you can use the [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator)

```
if ( a != null ) a else b
// equivalent to
a ?: b
```

Answer (score 47):

Some *corner cases* not mentioned in other answers.

Since appearance of [takeIf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) in [Kotlin 1.1](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#also-takeif-and-takeunless) the ternary operator `a ? b : c` can also be expressed like this:

```
b.takeIf { a } ?: c
```

This becomes even shorter in case c is `null`:

```
b.takeIf { a }
```

A general workaround to make `b` lazily-evaluated:

```
true.takeIf { a }?.let { b } ?: c
```

---

Also note that typical in Java world null checks like `value != null ? value : defaultValue` translate in ideomatic Kotlin to just `value ?: defaultValue`.

Similar `a != null ? b : c` can be translated to `a?.let { b } ?: c`.

---

See is also `Boolean?.ifTrue` proposal in [KT-6938](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6938/BooleanifTrue#focus=Comments-27-5982752.0-0) which should allow to streamline `a ? b : null` expressions to `a.ifTrue { b }` without prematurely evaluating the `b`.

Comment: How is `b.takeIf { a } ?: c` shorter and more readable than `if (a) b else c`? Terneray operator is certainly a missing feature in Kotlin since variable names and the condition can be long and make you split the line which is bad

Comment: It should also be noted that `takeIf` always evaluates the true-case (here `a`). Not only may that expression be computed uselessly if `a` happens to be false, but you can't benefit from smart casts à la `if (a is Int) { a + 3 }`.

Comment: @TheOperator, wrong. `{ a }` is a lazily evaluated lambda.

Comment: I wrote it wrong, should be "always evaluates the true-case (here `b`)".
But even `{ a }`, while lazy, _must_ be evaluated to determine the result of the expression.

Comment: `b.takeIf { a }` is technically equivalent to `b = a`

Comment: Use `a?.let{b}?:c` instead of takeIf to avoid evaluating b. Also reads more like the ternary operator

Answer (score 39):

There is **no ternary operator** in kotlin, as the **`if else`** block returns the value.

so, you can do:
`val max = if (a > b) a else b`
instead of java's `max = (a > b) ? b : c`

We can also use **`when`** construction, it also returns value:

```
val max = when(a > b) {
    true -> a
    false -> b
}
```

Here is the link for kotlin documentation : [Control Flow: if, when, for, while](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

Answer (score 38):

For myself I use following extension functions:

```
fun T?.or<T>(default: T): T = if (this == null) default else this 
fun T?.or<T>(compute: () -> T): T = if (this == null) compute() else this
```

First one will return provided default value in case object equals null. Second will evaluate expression provided in lambda in the same case.

Usage:

```
1) e?.getMessage().or("unknown")
2) obj?.lastMessage?.timestamp.or { Date() }
```

Personally for me code above more readable than `if` construction inlining

Comment: It's not that relevant to the question, but why not use __?:__, the _elvis operator_?
The first function would be replaced with
`e.getMessage() ?: "unknown"`.

The second can be expressed as
`obj?.lastMessage?.timestamp ?: { Date() }()`

Comment: @hotkey there is no special purpose for that. From my point of view it's looks more consistent and visually less noisy in chain operations as you shouldn't wrap construction in the brackets

Comment: @ruX the elvis operator is specifically for this and your use is rather unusual.

Comment: While ?: is fine, let's not go too far down the road to Perl.

Answer (score 36):

#### if condition is false then `"wrong"`, otherwise it's some `string()`

Let's consider the following prototype before writing a ternary conditional operator:

```
if (!answer.isSuccessful()) {
    result = "wrong"
} else {
    result = answer.body().string()
}
return result
```

---

### Solutions

You can use `!` (logical not) operator in Kotlin's `if-expression`:

```
return if (!answer.isSuccessful()) "wrong" else answer.body().string()
```

It can be much better if you flip `if-expression` (expression without `!` operator):

```
return if (answer.isSuccessful()) answer.body().string() else "wrong"
```

---

Kotlin’s Elvis operator `?:` can do a job even better:

```
return answer.body()?.string() ?: "wrong"
```

---

Also, use an `Extension function` for the corresponding `Answer` class:

```
fun Answer.bodyOrNull(): Body? = if (isSuccessful()) body() else null
```

---

In the `Extension function` you can reduce a code thanks to `Elvis operator`:

```
return answer.bodyOrNull()?.string() ?: "wrong"
```

---

Or just use `when` conditional expression:

```
when (!answer.isSuccessful()) {
    parseInt(str) -> result = "wrong"
    else -> result = answer.body().string()
}
```

Comment: I'm a few tens of hours into my Kotlin journey, and I am surprised how often an extension method is the right answer.  Often, I find I can't use the `?.` and `?:` operators because I'm wanting to pass the `Type?` to a method elsewhere, rather than invoke a method on *it*. (eg. pass a `String?` to `DateTimeFormatter. for parsing).  In that case, we're back to an `if (a != null) DateTimeFormatter.parse(s)`. But quick extension method 'turns it around' to `s?/toSpecialDate()` and almost always helps shove details out of the flow of the logic! I am loving Kotlin :-)

Answer (score 31):

> In Kotlin, `if` is an expression, i.e. it returns a value. Therefore
>   there is no ternary operator `(condition ? then : else)`, because
>   ordinary if works fine in this role.  [manual source from here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

```
// Traditional usage 
var max = a 
if (a < b) max = b

// With else 
var max: Int
if (a > b) {
    max = a
} else {
    max = b
}

// As expression 
val max = if (a > b) a else b
```

Answer (score 27):

Take a look at the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html):

> In Kotlin, if is an expression, i.e. it returns a value. Therefore there
>   is no ternary operator (condition ? then : else),
>   because ordinary if works fine in this role.

Answer (score 22):

Another interesting approach would be to use `when`:

```
when(a) {
  true -> b
  false -> c
}
```

Can be quite handy in some more complex scenarios. And honestly, it's more readable for me than `if ... else ...`

Answer (score 18):

Java

```
int temp = a ? b : c;
```

Equivalent to Kotlin：

```
var temp = if (a) b else c
```

Answer (score 16):

Kotlin doesn't have a ternary operator. You can use the regular `if` expression as shown below:

`if (condition) exp1 else exp2`

Also in addition to the fact that `if` in Kotlin is not a statement but an expression (i.e. it evaluates to a value), in the case where you have multiple statements inside the body of an `if` branch (or the body of `else` or `else if`), the last line of the block is the value of that branch. For example:

```
if (a>b) {
    println("a is greater than b")
    a // value of this if
} else {
    println("b is greater than a")
    b // value of else
}
```

Answer (score 15):

There is no ternary operator in Kotlin. It seems problematic at the first glance. But think we can do it with inline if else statement because this is expression here. Simply we have to do -

```
var number = if(n>0) "Positive" else "Negetive"
```

Here we can else if block too as many as we need. Like-

```
var number = if(n>0) "Positive" else if(n<0) "Negative" else "Zero"
```

So this line is so simple and much readable than ternary operator. when we use more than one ternary operator in java it seems horrible. But here we have a clear syntax. even we can write it in multiple line too.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `var a= if (a) b else c` in place of the ternary operator.

Another good concept of kotlin is the Elvis operator. You don't need to check null every time.

```
val l = b?.length ?: -1
```

This will return length if b is not null otherwise it executes the right side statement.

Answer (score 13):

when replaces the switch operator of C-like languages. In the simplest form it looks like this

```
when (x) {
    1 -> print("x == 1")
    2 -> print("x == 2")
    else -> {
        print("x is neither 1 nor 2")
    }
}
```

Comment: True, but the example you show has `when` as a statement, not an expression. A more relevant comparison with ternary conditional expressions would be to have each branch return a value, such that the entire when expression evaluates to a value (as happens with ternary conditionals).

Answer (score 13):

as Drew Noakes quoted, kotlin use if statement as expression,
so Ternary Conditional Operator is not necessary anymore,

but with the extension function and infix overloading, you could implement that yourself, here is an example

```
infix fun <T> Boolean.then(value: T?) = TernaryExpression(this, value)

class TernaryExpression<out T>(val flag: Boolean, val truly: T?) {
    infix fun <T> or(falsy: T?) = if (flag) truly else falsy
}
```

then use it like this

```
val grade = 90
val clazz = (grade > 80) then "A" or "B"
```

Comment: Maybe remove <T> better？infix fun or(falsy: T?) = if (flag) truly else falsy

Comment: But add <T> can make it work: (grade > 80) then null or "B"

Comment: This is really cool, I'm going to use it :P But do note that, unless I'm mistaken, it'll cause an object allocation every single time it's called. Not a huge deal, but worth knowing it's not a zero cost abstraction.

Comment: There could be unwanted side-effect because both `truly` and `falsy` must be evaluated. Writing `(grade > 80) then a() or b()` will invoke both `a()` and `b()`, but `if (grade > 80) a() else b()` will invoke either `a()` or `b()`, but not both.

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this:

```kotlin
val ans = (exp1 == exp2) then "yes" ?: "no"
```

by using this extension:

```kotlin
infix fun<T> Boolean.then(first: T): T? = if (this) first else null
```

P.S: Don't modify the above infix function to accept `first: T?`, the expression will become logically incorrect. Eg: If you modify it to accept nullable `first: T?`, then `val ans = (true == true) then null ?: "abcd"`, `ans` will be `"abcd"`, which would not be correct.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I came up with this: https://pl.kotl.in/tB7xXs6lR. Of course, the performance would be bad as it creates an intermediate object.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it many way in Kotlin

1. Using if

   ```
   if(a) b else c
   ```
2. Using when

   ```
   when (a) { 
       true -> print("value b") 
       false -> print("value c") 
       else -> {  
           print("default return in any other case") 
       } 
   }
   ```
3. Null Safety

   ```
   val a = b ?: c
   ```

Answer (score 9):

There is no ternary operation in Kotlin, but there are some fun ways to work around that.  As others have pointed out, a direct translation into Kotlin would look like this:

```
val x = if (condition) result1 else result2
```

But, personally, I think that can get a bit cluttered and hard to read.  There are some other options built into the library.  You can use takeIf {} with an elvis operator:

```
val x = result1.takeIf { condition } ?: result2
```

What is happening there is that the takeIf { } command returns either your result1 or null, and the elvis operator handles the null option.  There are some additional options, takeUnless { }, for example:

```
val x = result1.takeUnless { condition } ?: result2
```

The language is clear, you know what that's doing.

If it's a commonly used condition, you could also do something fun like use an inline extension method.  Let's assume we want to track a game score as an Int, for example, and we want to always return 0 if a given condition is not met:

```
inline fun Int.zeroIfFalse(func: () -> Boolean) : Int = if (!func.invoke()) 0 else this
```

Ok, that seems ugly.  But consider how it looks when it is used:

```
var score = 0
val twoPointer = 2
val threePointer = 3

score += twoPointer.zeroIfFalse { scoreCondition } 
score += threePointer.zeroIfFalse { scoreCondition }
```

As you can see, Kotlin offers a lot of flexibility in how you choose to express your code.  There are countless variations of my examples and probably ways I haven't even discovered yet.  I hope this helps!

Comment: `takeIf` is my favorite option indeed, very elegant.

Answer (score 8):

Remember **Ternary operator** and **Elvis operator** hold separate meanings in *Kotlin* unlike in many popular languages. Doing `expression? value1: value2` would give you bad words by the *Kotlin* compiler, unlike any other language as there is **no ternary operator in Kotlin** as mentioned in the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html). The reason is that the **if, when and try-catch** statements themselves return values.

So, doing `expression? value1: value2` can be replaced by

> val max = if (a > b) 
>       print("Choose a")
>    else
>       print("Choose b")

The **Elvis operator** that *Kotlin* has, works only in the case of nullable variables ex.:

> If I do something like `value3 = value1 ?: value2` then if *value1* is *null* then *value2* would be returned otherwise *value1* would be returned.

A more clear understanding can be achieved from [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253107/what-does-do-in-kotlin-elvis-operator/54988951#54988951).

Answer (score 6):

If you do not what to use the standard notation you can also create/simulate it using [infix](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) with something like this:

create a class to hold your target and result:

```
data class Ternary<T>(val target: T, val result: Boolean)
```

create some infix functions to simulate a ternary operation

```
infix fun <T> Boolean.then(target: T): Ternary<T> {
    return Ternary(target, this)
}

infix fun <T> Ternary<T>.or(target: T): T {
    return if (this.result) this.target else target
}
```

Then you will be able to use it like this:

```
val collection: List<Int> = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)

var exampleOne = collection.isEmpty() then "yes" or "no"
var exampleTwo = (collection.isNotEmpty() && collection.contains(2)) then "yes" or "no"
var exampleThree = collection.contains(1) then "yes" or "no"
```

Comment: To have it completely equivalent to an actual ternary operator, the target values can also be lambda supplying T

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `if` expression for this in Kotlin. In Kotlin `if` is an expression with a result value. So in Kotlin, we can write

```
fun max(a: Int, b: Int) = if (a > b) a else b
```

and in Java, we can achieve the same but with larger code

```
int max(int a, int b) {
return a > b ? a : b
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would one use something like this:

```
when(a) {
  true -> b
  false -> b
}
```

when you can actually use something like this (`a` is boolean in this case):

```
when {
  a -> b
  else -> b
}
```

Comment: Because the first one is semantically clear & easily understandable to someone else reading it even if they're not familiar w/Kotlin, while the 2nd one is not.

Comment: Well, you've got the point, however I can't understand why Kotlin developers didn't introduce ternary expression

Comment: I think `? and :` contradicts with the nullable/ type declaration rather than a type check. Apart from it I don't see any reason.

I think someone would have definitely put some thought, if there is inline if-else condition check. Let's wait and see in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers here with e.g. `takeIf` assume something like `x = (a != null) ? a : c` or `x = (a != null) ? a.method() : c` but this is not in fact equivalent to `x = a ? b : c`

To achieve a true equivalent of the ternary operator with null safety-check (i.e. `x = (a != null) ? b : c`) you can use `let` instead of `takeIf`, i.e.

> val x = a?.let {b} ?: c

where b may or may not be a method that invokes something on a.

Answer (score 1):

Another short approach to use

```
val value : String = "Kotlin"

value ?: ""
```

Here kotlin itself checks null value and if it is null then it passes empty string value.

Answer (score 1):

When working with apply(), let seems very handy when dealing with ternary operations, as it is more elegant and give you room

```
val columns: List<String> = ...
val band = Band().apply {
    name = columns[0]
    album = columns[1]
    year = columns[2].takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.let { it.toInt() } ?: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no ternary operator in Kotlin, the most closed are the below two cases,

- If else as expression statement

> `val a = true if(a) print("A is true") else print("A is false")`

- Elvis operator

> If the expression to the left of ?: is not null, the elvis operator
>   returns it, otherwise it returns the expression to the right. Note
>   that the right-hand side expression is evaluated only if the left-hand
>   side is null.

```
 val name = node.getName() ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("name expected")
```

[Reference docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can use ternary operation like this: `val x = if(a) "add b" else "add c"`

Comment: This question has been answered already enough, and has not been updated recently. There's no need to post now another answer that doesn't differ from earlier ones.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, if is a statement but, in Kotlin if is an expression. It is called an expression because it compares the values of a and b and returns the maximum value. Therfore, in Kotlin there is no ternary operator (a>b)?a:b because it is replaced by the if expression.

Answer (score 0):

With the following infix functions I can cover many common use cases pretty much the same way it can be done in Python :

```
class TestKotlinTernaryConditionalOperator {

    @Test
    fun testAndOrInfixFunctions() {
        Assertions.assertThat(true and "yes" or "no").isEqualTo("yes")
        Assertions.assertThat(false and "yes" or "no").isEqualTo("no")

        Assertions.assertThat("A" and "yes" or "no").isEqualTo("yes")
        Assertions.assertThat("" and "yes" or "no").isEqualTo("no")

        Assertions.assertThat(1 and "yes" or "no").isEqualTo("yes")
        Assertions.assertThat(0 and "yes" or "no").isEqualTo("no")

        Assertions.assertThat(Date() and "yes" or "no").isEqualTo("yes")
        @Suppress("CAST_NEVER_SUCCEEDS")
        Assertions.assertThat(null as Date? and "yes" or "no").isEqualTo("no")
    }
}

infix fun <E> Boolean?.and(other: E?): E? = if (this == true) other else null
infix fun <E> CharSequence?.and(other: E?): E? = if (!(this ?: "").isEmpty()) other else null
infix fun <E> Number?.and(other: E?): E? = if (this?.toInt() ?: 0 != 0) other else null
infix fun <E> Any?.and(other: E?): E? = if (this != null) other else null
infix fun <E> E?.or(other: E?): E? = this ?: other
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use **ifEmpty** function also just like below.

```
 val userName="anystring"
 textview.text = userName.ifEmpty { "otherstring" }
```

Answer (score -1):

> example:   **var energy: Int = data?.get(position)?.energy?.toInt() ?: 0**

In kotlin if you are using  **?:**  it will work like if the statement will return null then  **?: 0** it will take 0 or whatever you have write this side.

Answer (score -1):

fun max(x:Int,y:Int) : String = if (x>y) "max = $x" else "max = $y"

> inline funcation