# Kotlin Null safety warning Unexpected tokens (use ; to seperate expressions on the same line)

Tags: android, null, kotlin, warnings, kotlin-null-safety

I was trying [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) in Kotlin code in my application and received following warning:

```
Unexpected tokens (use ; to seperate expressions on the same line)
```

Code:

```
    var key: String = "KEY is"
    /* "check" is name of String variable which can be null
    Warning coming on following statement*/
    var str : String = check?key.replace("KEY", "ABDS-ASDSA-DSSS")?:check
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you want to use the Elvis operator? None of your variables are nullable, so it is pointless. Also, you never initialize `check`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin Ternary Conditional Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500/kotlin-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not understand why you need any null safe operators here. None of your variables are nullable.

---

You wrote

```
check?key.replace("KEY", "ABDS-ASDSA-DSSS")?:check
```

`?` (after `check`) is not an operator in Kotlin.

You may have wanted the [ternary conditional operator, which is simply replaced by `if`/`else`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500/kotlin-ternary-conditional-operator).

Judging from your comment, you seem to want the [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) operator though, which is `?.`, not `?`.

```
check?.key?.replace("KEY", "ABDS-ASDSA-DSSS") ?: check
```

There is a difference between the [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) and the safe call operator. The Elvis operator works with an expression while the safe call operator is simply **a null-safe property access or method call**.

The Elvis operator returns its first operand if it is not null, and returns the second operand otherwise.

The `?.` operator returns `null` if the receiver is null, otherwise, it returns the result of the call.

Comment: Thank you. Actually the actual code differs from the code in question.  Can you edit the question?

Comment: @MalwinderSingh what do you mean? If there is something missing in the question only you can add it - you are the asker and I do not know what you wish to add

Comment: I was asking about what changes need to be made in question to clarify the problem.

Comment: @MalwinderSingh ah - what are you trying to accomplish with `check` and `key`? What do you need `?:` for?

Answer (score 0):

kotlin does not support ternary operator.

and even `check` is not `boolean` variable in your case make it boolean or use like

```
var check: String = "something here"
 var key: String = "KEY is"
/*Warning coming on following statement*/
 var str : String = key.replace("KEY", "ABDS-ASDSA-DSSS")?:check
```

Comment: Thanks @Irony Stack. Actually I was trying to use Elvis operator of Kotlin (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator). Can you tell me why is Elvis operator not working?

Comment: but key is not a property of `check` you can not use it like that

Comment: @MalwinderSingh you misunderstood the concept of elvis operator, in this statement `val l = b?.length ?: -1`  2nd operator `?:` just before -1 is elvice operator not the one  before .length

Comment: I tried your solution. It is showing warning: `Elvis operator (?:) always returns the left operand of non-nullable type String`