# What does ?: do in Kotlin? (Elvis Operator)

Tags: kotlin

I can't figure out what `?:` does in for example this case

```
val list = mutableList ?: mutableListOf()
```

and why can it be modified to this

```
val list = if (mutableList != null) mutableList else mutableListOf()
```

Comment: Return left side if it's not null, otherwise return right side. The first expression is short notation for the second expression. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator

Comment: That's the same as ?? in Flutter, which means if null then blah blah blah

Answer (score 228, accepted):

*TL;DR: If the resulting object reference [first operand] is not `null`, it is returned. Otherwise the value of the second operand (which may be `null`) is returned.* Additionally, the operator can throw an exception if null is returned.

---

The **Elvis operator** is part of many programming languages, e.g. Kotlin but also Groovy or C#.
I find the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) definition pretty accurate:

> In certain computer programming languages, the **Elvis operator** `?:` is a *binary operator* that returns its first operand if that operand is `true`, and otherwise evaluates and returns its second operand. It is a **variant of the ternary conditional operator**, `? :`, found in those languages (and many others): the Elvis operator is the **ternary operator with its second operand omitted**.

The following is especially true for Kotlin:

> Some computer programming languages have different semantics for this operator. Instead of the first operand having to result in a boolean, **it must result in an object reference**. If the resulting object reference is not `null`, it is returned. Otherwise the value of the second operand (which may be `null`) is returned. If the second operand is null, the operator is also able to throw an exception.

An example:

```
x ?: y // yields `x` if `x` is not null, `y` otherwise.
x ?: throw SomeException() // yields `x` if `x` is not null, throws SomeException otherwise
```

Comment: C# does not have the Elvis operator in the strict sense. In C# we refer to `?.` as the Elvis operator, but it is written differently - `.` instead of `:` - and it behaves differently - it is a safe navigation operator. Short-circuit OR operator `||` and null-coalescing operator `??` cover the behaviors of the original `?:` operator, for booleans and references respectively.

Answer (score 160):

The **Elvis Operator** is represented by a question mark followed by a colon: **`?:`** and it can be used with this syntax:

```
first operand ?: second operand
```

It enables you to write a consise code, and works as such:

If `first operand` **isn't null**, then it will be returned. If it **is null**, then the `second operand` will be returned. This can be used to guarantee that an expression won't return a null value, as you'll provide a non-nullable value if the provided value is null.

---

For example(in Kotlin):

```
fun retrieveString(): String {    //Notice that this type isn't nullable
    val nullableVariable: String? = getPotentialNull() //This variable may be null
    
    return nullableVariable ?: "Secondary Not-Null String"
}
```

In this case, if the computed value of `getPotentialNull` is not null, it will be returned by `retrieveString`; If it is null, the second expression `"Secondary Not-Null String"` will be returned instead.

Also note that the right-hand side expression is evaluated **only** if the left-hand side is **null**.

In Kotlin, you could use any expression as `second operand`, such as a `throw Exception` expression

```
return nullVariable ?: throw IllegalResponseException("My inner function returned null! Oh no!")
```

---

The name Elvis Operator comes from the famous American singer **Elvis Presley**. His hairstyle resembles a Question Mark

[image: Elvis QuestionMark]

*Source: Wojda, I. Moskala, M. Android Development with Kotlin. 2017. Packt Publishing*

Comment: 20 points for the origination!

Answer (score 52):

This is called the [Elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) and it does... Exactly what you've described in your question. If its left hand side is a `null` value, it returns the right side instead, sort of as a fallback. Otherwise it just returns the value on the left hand side.

`a ?: b` is just shorthand for `if (a != null) a else b`.

Some more examples with types:

```
val x: String? = "foo"
val y: String = x ?: "bar"      // "foo", because x was non-null    

val a: String? = null
val b: String = a ?: "bar"      // "bar", because a was null
```

Comment: if you come from java, it's more a shorthand for: `a != null ? a : b`

Answer (score 10):

Let's take a look at the [defintion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator):

> When we have a nullable reference r, we can say "if r is not null, use
>   it, otherwise use some non-null value x":

The `?:` (Elvis) operator avoids verbosity and makes your code really concise.

For example, a lot of collection extension functions return `null` as fallback.

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).firstOrNull { it == 4 } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Ups")
```

`?:` gives you a way to handle the fallback case elgantely even if you have multiple layers of fallback. If so, you can simply chain multiply Elvis operators, like here:

```
val l = listOf(1, 2, 3)

val x = l.firstOrNull { it == 4 } ?: l.firstOrNull { it == 5 } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Ups")
```

If you would express the same with if else it would be a lot more code which is harder to read.

Answer (score 9):

The elvis operator in Kotlin is used for null safety.

```
x = a ?: b
```

In the above code, `x` will be assigned the value of `a` if a is not `null` and `b` if `a` is `null`.

The equivalent kotlin code without using the elvis operator is below:

```
x = if(a == null) b else a
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider below example,

```
var myStr:String? = null

//trying to find out length of myStr, but it could be null, so a null check can be put as,

val len = if (myStr != null){
    myStr.length
}
else{
    -1
}
```

Using the **elvis** operator, the above code can be written in a single line

```
val len = myStr?.length ?: -1     // will return -1 if myStr is null else will return length
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what has been already stated there is one good pattern that was not obvious for me, but which is common, e.g. you're writing a long function, but if something is *null* there is no sense to continue and the only thing you can do is to return from the function. Normally you'd write

```
something = expression
if (something == null) {
       return
}
```

With elvis it becomes shorter and more elegant:

```
something = expression ?: return
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply we can say that, you have two hands. You want to know, is your left hand working right now?. If left hand not working, `return` `empty` else `busy`

Example for Java:

```
private int a;
if(a != null){
    println("a is not null, Value is: "+a)
}
else{
    println("a is null")
}
```

Example for Kotlin:

```
val a : Int = 5
val l : Int = if (a != null) a.length else "a is null"
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if the left side of Elvis returns null for some reason, returns the right side instead.

i.e.

```
val number: Int? = null
println(number ?: "Number is null")
```

So, **if number is NOT null**,  it will print number, **otherwise** will print "Number is null".

Answer (score 3):

A little addition though is this

```
X = A ?: B
```

`X` will still be `null` if both `A` and `B` evaluate to `null`

Therefore, if you want `X` to always be `non-null`, make sure `B` is always a `non-null` or that `B` always evaluates to `non-null` if it's a function or expression.

Answer (score 2):

we use the Elvis operator to make sure we don't have a null in our result and if we have a null we determine how we deal with this null value by continuing in our program and returning a specific given value
for example **
[if the left side is not null do code on the left side else do the code on right side ]

```
 val currentPage = params.key ?: 1 //If the current page is null get the first page.
```