# How to get class of Any? variable in Kotlin?

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I want my `equals` to compare class too and I wrote

```
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return this::class == other::class && ...

    }
```

unfortunately it swears

```
Expression in a class literal has a nullable type 'Any?', use !! to make the type non-nullable
```

But I want to compare with `null`s too. What about glorious "null safety"? They forgot it for reflection? I didn't find `?::` operator or something.

Comment: Is this equals-method reused in different classes?

Comment: @D3xter yes in subclasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about this. The class is actually not different between a `String` and a `String?`, it's only the type that differs. You cannot invoke that operator on nullable types since it could mean you invoke it on `null` which would lead to a `NullPointerException`:

```
val x: String? = null
x!!::class //throws NPE
```

With the help of the scope function `let` you can ensure it isn't `null` and use the [class literal syntax](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references):

```
return other?.let { this::class == other::class } ?: false
```

The [Elvis operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48254829/8073652) `?:` is used to handle the `null` case by making the expression `false` (not equal).