# How to handle the null scenario with kotlinx-coroutines-reactive?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

`kotlinx-coroutines-reactive` makes `org.reactivestreams.Publisher` to have `awaitXXX` methods:

```
val person = peopleReactiveRepository.findById(personId).awaitSingle()
```

If there is no person can be found by a person ID, this invocation will throw NoSuchElementException and **this exception cannot be handled in the user code directly**. And Spring MVC `ExceptionHandler` can not translate this exception into a user-friendly response.

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value received via onNext for awaitSingle
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.reactive.AwaitKt$awaitOne$$inlined$suspendCancellableCoroutine$lambda$1.onComplete(Await.kt:131) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactive-0.22.1.jar:na]
at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onComplete(StrictSubscriber.java:123) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:1327) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHide.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:130) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ObservableToPublisher$1.onComplete(ObservableToPublisher.java:78) ~[mongodb-driver-reactivestreams-1.6.0.jar:na]
```

One of approaches I can figure out is in the following:

```
val person = peopleRepository.findById(personId).awaitFirstOrDefault(null)

if (person == null) {
    // do something
}
```

But I do not think it is an elegant way. For example, can provide a method named `awaitSingleOptional`.

Is there any better Kotlin way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Thanks for the idea: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/224

Comment: hey, did you notice the new feature? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48680672/8073652

Answer (score 6):

There are no standard `Optional` wrappers in Kotlin. You can use [the `let` function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) for such cases:

```
val person = peopleRepository.findById(personId).awaitFirstOrDefault(null)?.let {
    // do
}
```

If the await-expression evaluates to the default `null`, the `let` invocation will also evaluate to `null`. If you need to handle this case, the [Elvis operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48254829/8073652) can be used:

```
.let {...} ?: throw IllegalStateException()
```

Comment: Using `let` over `Option` is more idiomatic for kotlin, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html which mentions `let` but not `Option`/`Optional`

Answer (score 3):

An Extension `awaitFirstOrNull()` has been made available in the recent `kotlinx.coroutines` release [**0.22.2**](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases/tag/0.22.2). See this [PR](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/225/files).

Taken from the release notes:

> Reactive: Added `awaitFirstOrDefault` and `awaitFirstOrNull` extensions (see #224, PR by @konrad-kaminski).

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use `Optional` wrappers if you are programming in a functional way.

If you want to get your toes wet with functional programming, you can pick up [Arrow](http://arrow-kt.io/docs/) which has the [Option](http://arrow-kt.io/docs/datatypes/option/) and the [Try](http://arrow-kt.io/docs/datatypes/try/) data types for this purpose.

Using `?.let` is another option but it won't help you much with reactive programming.

There is also the [`Notification`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Notification.html) class in ReactiveX which will lets you handle an erroneous scenario if you are doing [Railway Oriented Programming](https://www.slideshare.net/ScottWlaschin/railway-oriented-programming).

Comment: What is Optional, I am on Kotlin JS?

Comment: No, `Optional` is part of the JDK. `Option` is part of Arrow.

Comment: What is Arrow, I am also calling from Objective C?

Comment: The question is tagged with [kotlin] and [kotlinx.coroutines] so I don't know how Objective C might be involved. Arrow is a library for functional programming, there is a link in my answer.