# Boolean expression with nullable variables

Tags: kotlin

I am tinkering around with Kotlin and I am trying to wrap my head around how nullable variables work in Kotlin. Here I have a piece of code that does a boolean check to see if a vehicle is over capacity.  Is the implementation a good way to work with nullable variables or is there a more elegant way ?

```kotlin
class Route(var vehicle: Vehicle?, var  jobs: List<Job>?) {
    constructor()
    constructor(vehicle: Vehicle?)

    fun isOverCapacity() : Boolean {
        val vehicleCapacity = vehicle?.capacity
        if (vehicleCapacity != null){
            val totalDemand = jobs?.sumBy { job -> job.demand }
            if (totalDemand != null) {
                return totalDemand > vehicleCapacity
            } 
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fun isOverCapacity(): Boolean {
    val vehicleCapacity = vehicle?.capacity ?: return false
    val totalDemand = jobs?.sumBy { job -> job.demand } ?: return false
    return totalDemand > vehicleCapacity
}
```

[What does ?: do in Kotlin? (Elvis Operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253107/what-does-do-in-kotlin-elvis-operator)

Answer (score 1):

By using kotlin std-lib dsl functional operators like [let](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html), [run](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html), [also](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html), [apply](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html), [use](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/use.html).

Use of `?.` -> if the object/value is not null then only call the next function.

- let -> returns the result of lambda expression.
- run -> returns the result of lambda expression passing this as receiver.
- also -> does operation and returns **itself** unlike the result of lambda.
- apply -> does operation and returns **itself** unlike the result of lambda passing this as receiver.
- use -> returns the result of lambda expression and closes the Closeable resource.

You can simplify the code as follows:

```kotlin
fun isOverCapacity() : Boolean =
    vehicle?.capacity?.let { vehicleCapacity ->
        jobs?.sumBy { job -> job.demand }?.let { totalDemand ->
            totalDemand > vehicleCapacity
        }
    } ?: false
```