# The difference between simply = assignment and also when getting an instance?

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the difference between simply = assignment and also when getting an instance? It seems that I am not catching some subtle points.

```
fun getInstance() = instance ?: synchronized(this){
            instance ?: FakeDatabase().also { instance = it }
        }
```

And

```
 fun getInstance() = instance ?: synchronized(this){
            instance = FakeDatabase()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is double check pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) written in kotlin.
Then you got the lock, might be second thread already create instance.
If it didn't - you create FakeDatabase() for return and also set it into instance variable

Answer (score 2):

The first major difference is returned value.

1. First method will return and instance of `FakeDatabase` because of [Elvis Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253107/what-does-do-in-kotlin-elvis-operator). it will return `instance` if not null or create one and assign it to `instance` and return.
2. Second method is not returning anything You can check it by calling it . it will return an `Unit` because you only have an assignment statement here. You can make it work by adding returned value for `synchronize` block at last line .

   ```
    fun getInstance() = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
        instance = FakeDatabase()
        instance!!
    }
   ```

But this just for demonstration purpose you can concise is as follows. You do not need `?:` inside again.

```
fun getInstance() = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
         FakeDatabase().also {  instance = it }
    }
```

If you have doubt about `also` its just an Scoping function. It allows to perform operation on an object and its return the same Object. in this case a `FakeDatabase` object after assigning it to `instance`.