# if condition inside the data class constructor in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a `data class` and I am creating an `object` of it. I am passing parameter values like this:

```
val leadDetails = AddLeadDetails(AgentId = agent.UserId,
    Name = leadUserName.text.toString().trim(),
    MobileNo = leadMobileNumber.text.toString().trim(),
    ProductType = productTypeId,
    LoanType = productTypeItem,
    ApplicationStatus = //if condition to put value i.e if(string == "s") "One value" else "Second Value"
    Amount = productAmountText.text.toString().trim(),
    Pincode = pinCodeText.text.toString().trim(),
    Remarks = customerRemarks.text.toString().trim(),
    Type = referType!!)
```

I want to add a value to `ApplicationStatus` based on `if` condition. How can I achieve that?

Comment: why not simply call a method with the logic you want?

Comment: Completely new to `Kotlin`. Sorry if it was a dumb question. But was not able to connect with `Java` mindset :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    TestClass(if (currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0L) "x" else "y")
}

data class TestClass(val text: String)
```

There's [no ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843369/8073652) in Kotlin since `if` is an expression as shown in the simplified example above.