# One line "if" operation

Tags: kotlin

I have following code:

```
 private fun setCashPaymentContainer(isSelected: Boolean) {      
        if (isSelected) {
            dataBinding.cashPaymentCheckImageViewContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            dataBinding.cashPaymentCheckImageViewContainer.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

It works fine, but I would like to improve it and write it as simplified and readable if else block.It would be nice if I can make a one line if else statement Please suggest.

Comment: yeah why would that not be possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Ternary Conditional Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500/kotlin-ternary-conditional-operator)

Comment: From context I assume this is Android. If you're including `Android KTX` in your project there's extension property available you can already use: [`View.isVisible`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).isVisible:kotlin.Boolean) so you can simply do `view.isVisible = isSelected`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an if expression:

```
dataBinding.cashPaymentCheckImageViewContainer.visibility = if(isSelected) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
```

...however in this case, [`isVisible`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#(android.view.View).isVisible:kotlin.Boolean) is better (credit: [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9241978/pawel)):

```
dataBinding.cashPaymentCheckImageViewContainer.isVisible = isSelected
```

Note: There are also [`isInvisible`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#isinvisible) and [`isGone`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#isgone).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, Kotlin allows this.

```
private fun setCashPaymentContainer(isSelected: Boolean) {      
    dataBinding.cashPaymentCheckImageViewContainer.visibility = when {
        isSelected -> View.VISIBLE
        else -> View.GONE
    }
}
```

You can actually make it even nicer (imo):

```
inline fun View.showIf(condition: (View) -> Boolean) {
    val shouldShow = condition(this) 

    this.visibility = when {
        shouldShow -> View.VISIBLE
        else -> View.GONE
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
private fun setCashPaymentContainer(isSelected: Boolean) {      
    dataBinding.cashPaymentCheckImageViewContainer.showIf { isSelected }
}
```