# Is there an kotlin equivalent of ?: java operator?

Tags: kotlin, conditional-operator

Reluctant kotlin newbie here.

Is there an kotlin equivalent of ?: java operator?

I tried searching on google. Most results talk about ?: (elvis operator) in kotlin.

Looking for a way to write this in kotlin:

```
//java example
//return condition ? a : b;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Ternary Conditional Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500/kotlin-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 3):

kotlin doesn't have ternary operator, but you can use `if`, `when`, `try catch` as [expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#if-expression)

```
return if (condition) a else b
```

Comment: In Kotlin, `if (…) … else …` effectively _is_ a ternary operator: it takes three expressions, and returns a value.  It may not _look_ like most other operators, but it's doing exactly the same as the Java/C-style `… ? … : …`.  (Which is why Kotlin doesn't need the latter.)

Answer (score 2):

`? :` is a [tenary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) which is currently not present in Kotlin. There are few discussions on adding this operator to the language e.g. [KT-5823 Support ternary conditional operator 'foo ? a : b'](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5823) .

The usual suggestion is to use an `if` statement as replacement.

Answer (score 2):

The Kotlin equivalent is:

```
if (a) b else c
```

That's the closest to the Java that you can get at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way to do it is this:

```
return when {
    condition -> a 
    else -> b
}
```

Comment: Why would this be the "nicest"? Using `if (a) b else c` seems the obvious choice.

Comment: Because `b` is equally important to `a`, and are on the same level of horizontal positioning, thus making code more readable. It is also easier to modify, etc.