# Conditions in Data class Kotlin

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, conditional-operator, data-class

so, I heard there are no ternary operators in kotlin, so, how can I achieve the following in kotlin data class, but i want only a part of the data from the data class to show in the recycler view based on a certain condition

below shows how it is done in **JS**

```
 {online.map(function(item){
     
         return (
          <div key={item.uid} >

  {item.Gender== 'Male' ?
          
          <li >

<div><img src={item.photoURL}/><p><b>{item.displayName}</b></p></div>
    </li>
         
: null}
                   
          </div>
    )
    })}
```

> `online` is an object that contains the list of user information
> `{item.Gender === 'Male' ?` checks and returns only users that are male

so, can that similar feature be achieved in Kotlin?

**Kotlin data class**

```
data class UserInfo(
    val uid: Uids) {
        data class Uids (
    var Gender: String? = null,
    var uid: String? = null,
    var displayName: String? = null,
    var photoURL: String? = null)
}
```

```
class BalAdapter(val context: Context, private val dataList: ArrayList<UserInfo.Uids>, private val layout: Int) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BalAdapter.Holder>() {
    lateinit var listener: (UserInfo.Uids) -> Unit
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        val item = dataList[position]
        holder.bindItems(item)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { listener(item) }

    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(layout, parent, false)
        return Holder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataList.size
    }


    inner class Holder(view: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view!!) {
        val recordCategory = view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.itemImage)
        val recordNote = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.firstname)
        val recordAmount = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lastname)

        fun bindItems(bal: UserInfo.Uids) {
            Picasso.get()
                .load(bal.photoURL)
                .resize(100, 100)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(recordCategory)
            recordNote?.text = bal.displayName
            recordAmount?.text = bal.email
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener.invoke(UserInfo.Uids())

                //  recordDeleteImageView.imageb
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*would the conditions be placed in the adapter, in the fragment class containing the recyclerView, or in the class that is populating the data class? and **how would it be done?***

Comment: why kotlin don't have ternary operator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500/kotlin-ternary-conditional-operator, and also, what is your question actually?

Comment: i want only a part of the data from the data class to show in the recycler view based on a certain condition

Comment: This is the answer you want? `val result  = online.map { it.Gender == "Male" }` ? `result` should be returns list of user with `Male` in gender

Comment: Yes, but in kotlin

Comment: this is kotlin bro

Comment: So, will I put it on the adapter class?

Comment: does ```.map```work with ArrayList from data class? from the docs, ```.map``` works with collections, so, will I have to change the ArrayList to a collection?

Comment: Yes, `.map` works for all list type. and can you show your works on adapter? Without your code in adapter I can't understand what you trying to ask.

Comment: You should sort out your data nicely before displaying it in UI

Comment: i've  added the adapter class

Answer (score 1):

Just create another method to update your value in adapter

```
class BalAdapter(val context: Context, private val dataList: ArrayList<UserInfo.Uids>, private val layout: Int) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BalAdapter.Holder>() {

    internal fun updateValue(userInfo: UserInfo) {
        dataList = userInfo
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Then, in your view, just call this function with latest value

```
val result  = UserInfo.map { it.Gender == "Male" }

balAdapter.updateValue(result)
```

Comment: There is no list as ```online```

Comment: The ```online``` was from the javascript code

Comment: Just replace `online` to your original list `UserInfo` ?

Comment: Please try it somehow, dont wait others to spoon-feed

Comment: I asked, because, it's saying ```unresolved reference: map```

Comment: this is what worked with the ```map``` ```ArrayList<UserInfo.Uids>()```