# Kotlin initializ val with conditions

Tags: kotlin

In c++ const can be defined by

```
void func(const int param) {
    const int VALUE = param > 0 ? param : 0;
    ...
}
```

In Kotlin I am trying to use `when`:

```
fun func(param: Int) {
    val VALUE = when(param)
    when(param) {
        param > 0 -> param // Error: expression `param > 0` is not Int
        else -> 0
    }
    ...
}
```

What is the kotlin way to say `expression ? value0 : value1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336500/how-to-write-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin if one line like this :

```
 var yourVAr=if(condition)value1 else value2
```